# Every two consecutive integers are coprime.

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing

I start with knowing that two numbers are coprime if:

$n*k + m*j = 1$

So, setting $k = a$ and j = $a+1$ I can solve as follows:

$n*a + m*a + a$

Then,

$a(n+m) + m = 1$

Where can I go from here?

Comment: You just need to find a linear combination of $a$ and $a+1$ that give $1$. That is the definition above that you stated, essentially.

Comment: @JasonPolak If it's not much of a hassle, could you try and explain a bit more? I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "linear combination"?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are any integers, a linear combination (or more precisely, $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination) of $a$ and $b$ in this setting means an expression of the form $ra + sb$ where $r$ and $s$ are integers. So $4a + 5b$ is an example of an (integer) linear combination of $a$ and $b$. If you can find $r$ and $s$ integers such that $ra + sb = 1$ then $a$ and $b$ are coprime. So you want to find $r$ and $s$, in your case, such that $r(a + 1) + sa = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not, $p\mid a$ and $p\mid a+1$ would give $p\mid (a+1)-a=1$ for a prime $p$, a contradiction. Or with your definition $1\cdot(a+1)-1\cdot (a)=1$.